# how to solve absolute inequality functions

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I have noticed in the past while solving inequality functions that when you want to change the inequality symbol you need to switch the $+$ or $-$ signs of the function itself.

How do I solve this equation  and draw it on a number line?

$${x:|x+3|>5}$$

Comment: Geometrically speaking, $|x+3|$ defines the distance between number $x$ and $-3$.

Comment: Draw -3 on a line and go for +5 and -5 around it.

Comment: @servabat Should it be drawn from 3 or -3?

Comment: -3 : $\left|x-y\right|$ is the distance between y and x as explained above.

Comment: To understand that better you can write it as a set of inequalities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algebraic solution:

If $\theta > 0$, then
$$\begin{array}[t]{l}|x-a|>\theta \iff x-a>\theta \,\text{ or }\, x-a<-\theta\\
 |x-a|<\theta \iff -\theta<x-a<\theta\\
|x-a|=\theta \iff x-a=\theta \,\text{  or  } \,x-a=-\theta
\end{array}$$

It is easy to verify the results geometrically.